# Source "forge-std/Script.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Tags: compiler-errors, solidity, cloud-foundry, smartcontracts, vscode-debugger

```
    pragma solidity  ^0.8.19;

   import { Script , console } from "forge-std/Script.sol";
```

## I was trying to add remappings.txt but not working

`# forge-std/=lib/forge-std/src/`

## forge remappings > remappings.txt

## please help me to fix this error !!